# pass table name as variable in SQL query C# windows application

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-code

I am trying to pass a table name in my insert query which is stored in a variable. What I am trying to do is that a list of table names a store in a "shopkeeper " table and now I have to select a certain table name from that shopkeeper table and insert that table name from the select query to the insert statement. I know it's a bit confusing but looking at code will help.

**Update**

I wanted to use table name as a variable that stores the name of the table in which I have to insert that all the value

```
    tring Query2 = "insert into Phones4u.'"+Table_Name+"'(Date, iemi_no , mobile_name, company, color, warranty_provider, invoice_from, stock_status) values('" + inventory_DGV.Rows[i].Cells["Date"].Value.ToString() + "','" + iemino + "', '" + inventory_DGV.Rows[i].Cells["Mobile_Name"].Value.ToString() + "', '" + inventory_DGV.Rows[i].Cells["Company"].Value.ToString() + "', '" + inventory_DGV.Rows[i].Cells["Color"].Value.ToString() + "', '" + inventory_DGV.Rows[i].Cells["Warranty_Provider"].Value.ToString() + "','" + inventory_DGV.Rows[i].Cells["Invoiced_Form"].Value.ToString() + "','" + status2 + "')";
```

in this query, the Table_Name variable has the value/name of the table in which value has to add. This Table_Name is getting assigned value from another select query

```
    string Query1 = "SELECT Shopkeeper_name FROM shopkeeper WHERE shop_name = '" + invoicedFrom_comboBox.ToString() + "'";

        MyConn2.Open();
        MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query1, MyConn2);
        MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
        MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();

        while (MyReader2.Read())
        {
            Table_Name = MyReader2["Shopkeeper_name"].ToString();

        }

        MyConn2.Close();
```

so this is the problem which I have to solve.

Comment: I should keep an accurate tally but anecdotal statistics would, I reckon, put the number of people turning up with SQL injection hack prone SQLs at about 95%. I'd love to know why that is.. Is the net really still these days stuffed full of awful tutorials that tell people to write SQL like `"SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Name = '" + bobbySurname + "'"` ? Have a read of https://bobby-tables.com

Comment: Following up on @CaiusJard comment, I'd also consider reading [How SQL Injection Works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15#how-sql-injection-works).

Comment: And the other bit that you should probably address at some point: In c# we name methods in PascalCase, and local variables in CamelCase. We don't use underscores and we strive to make variable names interesting and relevant as an aid to making code self documenting. We try to avoid naming them the type that they are together with a number to make them unique (MyConn, MyConn2, MyCommand4, MyReader2..)

Comment: Can we top this off with you need to dispose connection, command and reader with `using` blocks. Your database almost certainly has a denormalization problem if this is what you are trying to do. You probably need to combine all those dynamic tables into one

Comment: And to answer your question, you _can't_ use DDL identifiers (table names, column names, etc) as SQL parameters. Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to use a parameter in the one place you can't, and not in _any_ of the places you should?

Comment: `Phones4u.(?ProductID)` - productid should be a column of a table, not the name of a table. Do not store in table names information that should be in a column. Write a script to rebuild all these separate tables into one, with a product of column and this problem will disappear

Comment: I wanted to use table name as a variable that stores the name of the table in which I have to insert that all the value.

Comment: `string Query2 = "CREATE TABLE " + Dbname + "." + name + " (Date DATE,Entry_Name CHAR(50), Debit FLOAT, Credit FLOAT, Balance FLOAT, stock_status CHAR(50), Iemino bigint(20), Mobile_Name CHAR(50), Color CHAR(50))";`

This is a working query in which I have used variables for table creation @CaiusJard @charlieface @MarkBenningfield

Comment: Yes, I don't doubt you've cobbked together something that seems to work.. It's just all the horrific drawbacks it comes with. It's piling a hack on top of a bodge, when the proper solution is to re-engineer things

Comment: (My advice remains "do not store in a table name data that should live in a column")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable that has a table name in the query, where you have to mention table name and for that in my case you have to use query like that

```
string Query2 = "insert into " + Dbname + "." + Table_Name + 
                "(Date, Iemino , mobile_name, color, stock_status) values('" + 
                     inventory_DGV.Rows[i].Cells["Date"].Value.ToString() + "','" + 
                     iemino + "', '" + 
                     inventory_DGV.Rows[i].Cells["Mobile_Name"].Value.ToString() + "', '" + 
                     inventory_DGV.Rows[i].Cells["Color"].Value.ToString() + "', '" + status2 + "')";
```

Where `Dbname` is the database name and `Table_Name` variable has a table name, which in my case I got from running another query